# JDBC MySQL conect to fail over node very slow

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc, failover

My environment have 2 MySQL server (INS1 and INS2) and when I tested failover mode with down INS1 and driver creat connection to INS2 it has very very slow to connected (It has occur on Glassfish connection pool too.)

```
final String connstr = "jdbc:mysql://INS1,INS2:3306/mysql";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "xxx");
props.put("password", "xxx");
props.put("failOverReadOnly", "false");
props.put("roundRobinLoadBalance", "false");

return DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, props);
```

How to tune jdbc properties?

> run: When INS1 run. INFO: Connected in 350 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 16 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 15 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 17 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 15 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 16 ms BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
>
> run: When INS1 down. INFO: Connected in 1,380 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 1,060 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 1,058 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 1,060 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 1,055 ms
>
> INFO: Connected in 1,041 ms BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Timeout for socket connect (in milliseconds), with 0 being no timeout. Only works on JDK-1.4 or newer. Defaults to '0'.
props.put("connectTimeout", "100");

Comment: Yeah, I found after post. Orz